# Do we want to change the link about MathJax help?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, mathjax, hyperlinks

Astronomy Stack Exchange has MathJax enabled, allowing us to use LaTeX to write equations. Like other SE sites with MathJax, we have [a section in the editing help page on how to use LaTeX](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex). This section contains a "MathJax help" link at the end.

By default, the link points to [this page](https://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/texman/), but it turns the Community Team can change it to a different page, such as a post on our site's meta with a customized explanation of MathJax, or [this comprehensive meta post on Math Stack Exchange](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

In case folks want to change the link, we decided to start a meta discussion. If you have an idea for a page to link to, post it as an answer below. If there's a consensus about a specific option, the Community Team can make the change.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I prefer the link to the [Mathematics Meta SE page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Firstly it is explicitly specific to Mathjax and does not rely or seem to relate to Latex.  Mathjax and LaTex are similar but should not be considered the same.  Latex is for document production and much of it's documentation is just confusing for people using Mathjax.  It is also common to see LaTex users solve formatting problems by using external libraries which are not available to Mathjax users who need Mathjax specific methods.

Secondly it's a very comprehensive list of hints and tricks that makes it *relatively* easy for newer users to find out what they need than a simpler and less detailed account provides.  There's always going to be a learning curve, but that page gets you to what you need fairly directly without fuss.

Lastly the Mathematics Meta help page for Mathjax is updated reasonably frequently so I think we can reasonably say it is keeping up with changes specific to SE and not some other site's Mathjax reference version, which may not equate to what SE uses.  For that reason alone I think the Mathematic SE help page should be the *default* for *all* SE sites using Mathjax and I am surprised to find a Tex help page being used instead, but that's a subject for the main Meta SE site not here.

Comment: The "MathJax help" link on Astronomy.SE (and this Meta site) has been changed to point to [this Math Meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), per your suggestion. Let us know if you encounter any problems!